# Causes for EXC_BREAKPOINT crash

Tags: swift, debugging

I have this stack trace in Crashlytics:

[image]

The source code are running is below:

```
@objc private func playerTimerTick() {
    mediaDurationInSeconds = Int32(mediaDuration)
    mediaCurrentPositionInSeconds = Int32(currentTimeInSeconds)

    if elapsedTimeNeedStoreStartPosition {
        elapsedTimeNeedStoreStartPosition = false
        elapsedTimeStartPosition = mediaCurrentPositionInSeconds
    }
}
```

The line 1092 is `mediaDurationInSeconds = Int32(mediaDuration)`.

The `mediaDuration` variable is a Double type and receive a duration in seconds from a `AVURLAsset`.

This method (**playerTimerTick**) is running by a `Timer.scheduledTimer` every 1 second. I have already performed several debugs of this source code and this function and there is no crash. But in the release version is occurring with multiple users and without any explanation.

Has anyone ever had anything like this or do you have any idea what might be causing this crash?

Comment: You may need to use nslock

Comment: Can you check the **Device States** in your Crashlytics log? What are the **Free Space** and **Free RAM** values?

Comment: @E.Coms thanks. I'll read more about `NSLock` and try to solve this crash.

Comment: @AshleyMills the states are well diversified... **Free RAM**: 25%, 13%, 5% / **Free Space**: 50%, 24%, 5%

Comment: What is `mediaDuration` ? Are you sure the value never exceeds the range of `Int32` ?

Comment: @OOPer I think that would give EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION _"Not enough bits to represent the passed value"_

Comment: @OOPer the `mediaDuration` variable is a Double type.

Comment: @AshleyMills, you are mistaking something. `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` happens in simulators (x86 CPUs have reserved illegal instruction). In actual devices (ARM CPUs), it's `EXC_BREAKPOINT`.

Comment: @rafaeldepaula, are you sure the value never exceeds the range of `Int32` ? For example, when your app resumes from suspended, the variable has really an appropriate value?

Comment: @OOPer ah, interesting! That came from a playground so makes sense.

Comment: @OOPer the value of this variable only receives the duration in seconds of an audiobook chapter, to exceed the limit of Int32 would need to be a 590,000 hour audio.

Comment: I mean, at any use cases of your app, you need to confirm the variable holds the appropriate value as the duration. If all things working as you expect, this sort of crash may never happen. Check carefully.

Comment: Thanks @OOPer! I will put a test as a protection to verify that the value will not exceed

Comment: @rafaeldepaula, That may be a better way than checking your source code line by line... Hope it solves your issue.